# enum referencing in switch case

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

```
enum Color {RED, GREEN, BLUE};
class SwitchEnum
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Color c = Color.GREEN;
    switch(c)
    {
      case RED:
        System.out.println("red");
        break;
      case GREEN:
        System.out.println("green");
        break;
      case BLUE:
        System.out.println("blue");
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

The above code compiles fine and gives the expected output.

My question is why when creating the Color reference 'c' we needed to refer it through the name of the enum (i.e. Color.GREEN) but in the case block only the enum value sufficed. Shouldn't it have been

```
case Color.RED:
```

etc???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it shouldn't.  The Java compiler is smart enough to know that you are switching on a `Color` and so the language allows for this shortcut (and as Paul notes, requires it).  In fact, the whole compilation of a switch statement depends on the compiler knowing what you're switching on, since it translates the switch into a jump table based on the index of the enum value you specify.  Only very recently have you been able to switch on non-numerical things like a `String`.

The relevant part of the language spec is in [JLS Chapter 14.11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11):

> ```
> ...
> SwitchLabel:
>    case ConstantExpression :
>    case EnumConstantName :
>    default :
>
> EnumConstantName:
>    Identifier
> ```

If you're looking for insight into why the language was designed the way it was, that's going to be hard to answer objectively.  Language design is nuanced, and you have to consider that the assignment syntax was written years and years before enum support was added.

Comment: +1 In fact you *have* to use the shortcut. See [this interesting post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8481635/697449) for example.

Comment: @Paul: An enum switch case label **MUST** be the _unqualified_ name of an enum constant. thnx... got it...

Answer (score 2):

It is a language convention. Many different languages have enums, and not all make you do this. In the case of Java, you can do Color.RED or whatever, because of namespaces. By doing so, you can have multiple enums with the same variable names, and they don't clash.

The reason that the switch statement doesn't require you to do Color.RED (and allows you to simply state RED) is that the switch statement knows that it is an enum of type Color, and looks in that namespace.

Answer (score 1):

In the line

```
Color c = Color.GREEN;
```

the `Color.` is required because the Java compiler doesn't infer the type of the assigned expression (`Color.GREEN`) from the declaration (`Color c`). For the same reason, you have to write:

```
ArrayList<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and not simply

```
ArrayList<String> x = new ArrayList();
```

(This is actually partially fixed in Java 7 but that's another story.) In the `switch(...)` statement, the type of the `case` is inferred from the type of the `switch` however.